# How to calculate factorial variable into regression model?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, factorial

I'm using my own dataset, from my work. Dataset contains 12 variables.

```
Lp.     `PersonID`   Sex        `Seniority~ Job       `Present salary~       `Pay raise~ `Future salary~
  <dbl>          <dbl> <fct>            <dbl> <fct>                 <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1     1           26 MAN~               20 OPERATOR-~             23.2              1.3             24.5
2     2           34 MAN~               20 OPERATOR ~             21.6              1.3             22.9
3     3           36 MAN~               20 OPERATOR-~             22.2              1.3             23.5
4     4           37 MAN~               20 OPERATOR-~             23.2              1.3             24.5
5     5           62 MAN~               20 OPERATOR ~             21.5              1               22.5
6     6           66 MAN~               20 OPERATOR ~             20.8              1               21.8

'attitude grade' 'skill grade' 
<fct>            <fct>     
A                B
B                B
B                A
B                C
B                B
C                B
```

I'd like to do regression model, using "lm" function:

```
model1=lm(Dane$`Pay raise`~Dane$Seniority + Dane$'Present salary`+ Dane$Sex + Dane$Job +Dane$`attitude grade` +Dane$'Skill grade')
```

When I use `summary(model1)` R doesn't seem to understand factorial variable, beacuse it treats every variant of factorial variables as separate (for example R creates 3 different variables - "A attitude grade", "B attitude grade" - I want only one variable - "attitude grade" in general).

Comment: R treats factor variables as expected. It seems you are lacking the correct understanding of how categorial variables are treated in regression. I suggest doing some desk research via e.g. Google first. Here's one of the first search results for me that explains how factor variables are treated in R regression: http://courses.atlas.illinois.edu/spring2016/STAT/STAT200/RProgramming/RegressionFactors.html

Comment: Ok, so code is correct or not?

Comment: The way you shared the data isn't reproducible (as opposed to `dput` or using a built-in data set for the example) so it's hard to say if your code is correct or not, but I agree with @deschen that the problem is your interpretation of what you're seeing and your underlying understanding of how categorical variables are treated in a regression. Basically, in any regression, when you have a categorical variable you create fixed effects (1-hot encoded variables) for n-1 levels of the variable and drop one level for comparison. That's just how it works. I would suggest to delete the question.

Comment: The code looks correct, although you are using non-standard column names in your data and should convert them to proper R column names, which must not include whitespaces or tilde signs or any other special characters.

Comment: I can't reproduce your analysis, but I think you want to use the anova function to get an ANOVA table instead of the summary() function.